# Flutter - RefreshIndicator in TabBarView causing multiple renders

Tags: flutter, tabs, pull-to-refresh

I am using TabBarView with 4 tabs inside and every tab has its own RefreshIndicator which is used to perform GET request for specific data. The problem is that when for example I perform refresh on TAB 3, request is send from every other tabs as well, which is really heavy for network. Is it bug or am I missing something in my implementation ?

Comment: Please reproduce the problem in a simple example and then share that code here. Then people can look at it.

Comment: I have the same problem, still looking for a solution....

Comment: Did you fixed it ? @SimonovDmitriy